# Why passing by reference not working in c?

Tags: c, pointers

I was learning basics of `C` language and i had a problem about passing variables by Reference , here is my code:

```
int getd(int* p);
void main()
{
    int x = 10;
    getd(&x);
    printf("%d\n",x);

}
int getd(int* p)
{
    (*p) * 2;

}

> output: 10
```

why not print x = 20 ? i mean i double the pointer that point to variable x , so why the value of x still 10 ?

Comment: Uh, where's your `return` statement?  And why don't you *assign* the expression `*p * 2` to anything???

Comment: Then using call by reference, a `return` is not necessary. But it may a good idea to assign the calculated value to `p` ;). So you can change you `int` to `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `(*p) * 2;` means

1. read what is pointed at by `p`
2. multiply by 2

No update of values are done here.

It seems you should use `*p = (*p) * 2;` instead of `(*p) * 2;`.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add an = sign.

```
(*p) *= 2;
```

Your original line is just an expression, but it does not modify anything.

OTOH. your function doesn't return anything so it should be declared as `void`

The C language allows writting expressions that have no L-value to assign to. Some of them, such as a call to `printf` have side effects and are useful even if its result is just thrown away, but even if the expression has no side effects, it's allowed in C to have code that just evaluates an expression, such as yours.

Sometimes the compiler can evaluate it in compile-time, sometimes it detects that the evaluation operation won't alter the behaviour of the program and it will throw the whole expression away from the object code.

Comment: Correct on both counts: 1) The OP never assigned the result of his expression to anything (e.g. `(*p) *= 2;`), and 2) he should either a) return the value, or b) declare the function `void`.

Comment: Per your edit: correct on all *three* counts.  Not only isn't there an assignment to an L-value ... but a good optimizer could even eliminate the code entirely ;) My recommendation to the OP: 1) pass by value: `int getd(int p) {...}`, 2) return the computed value: `return p * 2;` 3) use getd() directly: `printf("%d\n",getd(x));`